# How can I proove only one of these three holds? $m>n, m=n, m<n$.

Tags: inequality, peano-axioms

I'm going to finish constructing real numbers from the Peano axiom.

I've just finished constructing natural numbers and integers and now I'm going to construct an inequality within the integer range, but I can't prove the most basic proposition.

How can I proove only one of these three holds?

$$\forall m,n\in\mathbb N, m>n, m=n, m<m$$

My try : It is easy to proobe that at most one of them holds. And I'll let first $m\ne n$. If $m\not>n$, then $m\notin \Bbb N+n$. I have no idea to go forth. Pleast help me.

Comment: This is the well-known trichotomy law for natural numbers. A reference with full proof can be found at the bottom of p. 84 of Enderton's Elements of Set Theory. The basic idea is to consider the set of naturals $n$ such that for all $m$ at least one condition holds, and show it contains $n=0$ by induction, and then prove the set itself is inductive and hence is all of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Does the employment of set theory imply that the values are necessarily finite? But, this is not general enough as one could argue that we may be dealing with a set of infinities, where some infinities are demonstrated to be weaker or stronger or even equal.